# Are seeded random numbers not consistent between python versions?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

#### Question:

Why are seeded random outputs seemingly different across python versions? Have I missed something obvious, is it a documented behavior (I could not find it)

#### Observed results:

An attempt to reproduce seeded random numbers across python versions produces different results:

```
# python 3.7
rachel = sorted(Random('rachel').sample(range(57), 6))
larry = sorted(Random('larry').sample(range(57), 6))
armin = sorted(Random('armin').sample(range(57), 6))
laura = sorted(Random('laura').sample(range(57), 6))
rachel, larry, armin, laura
```

**output:**

```
([8, 22, 27, 35, 45, 47],
 [10, 18, 20, 29, 45, 47],
 [4, 7, 15, 22, 47, 52],
 [5, 8, 37, 40, 50, 55])
```

#### Comparison point:

Whereas a screenshot from Raymond Hettinger's advanced python at Europycon 2011 is showing a different output - probably python 2.6 or 2.7: (the image quality is poor, but the results are clearly different)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the documentation for the [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) function in the `random` module you see that there is a note that in Python 3.2 a different version is used by default.

> With version 2 (the default), a str, bytes, or bytearray object gets converted to an int and all of its bits are used.
>
> With version 1 (provided for reproducing random sequences from older versions of Python), the algorithm for str and bytes generates a narrower range of seeds.

This seems enough to answer the fact of different sequences between the screenshot and your case.